# Notepad ++ some weird regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to remove a few things in a text file, but it would be waaay too much work to do it manually, i think im in need of a regex

Myname:Wow11:myemail@bsomeemail.com:2017-02-11:TT:D:none:John Doe

I want to remove everything except Wow11:myemail@someemail.com

How would that be possible ? thank you very much

Comment: How is it supposed to find that if it doesn't know where or what to look for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `^[^:]+:(([^:]+:?){2}):.+(\R)`
- **Replace With:** `\1\3`
- Check **regular expression**
- Click Replace or Replace All

**Explanations**
Here we try to determine sequences of something not a `:` followed by `:`, this is what `[^:]+:` should accomplish.

- the first such sequence after linestart `^` is ignored
- the second and third such sequences are stored into `\1` for reuse in the replacement by putting `([^:]+:?){2}` into another pair of parentheses
- everything after the third such sequence (`.+`) is again ignored
- *ignore* here means : not captured, not used for replacement
- the `\R` matches the linending and that is again captured for reuse during replacement into `\3`
- we use `\R` and `.+` to prevent that after the *replace all* has replaced all lines, what remains matches again and is replace a second time

Comment: Awesome, exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ to remove the unwanted text from your example text string above you would do the following:

- Select Search
- Select Replace
- Select a Search Mode of Regular expression

Find what:

```
\S+:(\S+:\S+@\S+\.com).*
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to put my two cents in:

```
^[^:]+:([^:]+:[^:]+).+$
```

Look for the above expression, turn on `MULTILINE` mode and replace the found match with `\1`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Qw5PWT/1/).